# Screenshot tool for BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, screenshot, mobile-website

I am working on a web development project that I want to make sure works well on the BlackBerry browser.  As part of both testing and documentation, I want to be able to take screenshots of my application and was wondering where to start.

I see there are a couple of pay applications on [BlackBerry App World](http://www.blackberry.com/appworld/) when I search for [screenshot](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/search/screenshot), but I am looking for recommendations or other options.  Specifically, I have a Bold 9700 (v5.0.0.296, platform 5.1.0.83).

It appears this feature is built into the iPhone, according to the [iPhone User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPhone_User_Guide.pdf).

> Take a screenshot of the iPhone
>   display: Quickly press and release the
>   Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the
>   same time.

Comment: It's true - that's how I get iPhone screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to write you're own app or service to make screenshots.

Use
[Display.screenshot(Bitmap bitmap)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29)
or
[Display.screenshot(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**Note: you should [sign](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp) app to use this api**

Comment: Because I may need my business people to also be able to capture screen shots, this may be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the developer tools installed, you can use "javaloader -u screenshot file.bmp" to capture a screenshot.  Otherwise, the easiest way is to install a PC app called [Master Control Program](http://mcpfx.com/news.php) which has the capability to capture screenshots as well (as long as you have your device connected to your PC with a USB cable).

Comment: Make sure to use the `JavaLoader.exe` included in JDE 7.0 (or eclipse plugin) if you need to capture on newer devices. Older javaloader versions do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I get BlackBerry screenshots in two ways:

-On real devices I connect them to my PC over USB and run `javaloader -u screenshot image.bmp` from the command line (as Marc says, it's included with the developer tools).

-The BlackBerry Simulator makes it easy to take screenshots by pressing F3 (or choosing Edit -> Save LCD Snapshot from the menu, note you can choose to save directly as a .png, which is handy).  You can change which phone model to simulate based on the SDK you have installed.  For the 9700 I think you will need the V5.0 OS SDK (I haven't tried that yet), which you can get from [here](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477).

Answer (score 1):

BBScreenShooter http://oppitronic.net/pb/ouiVC.php#BBScreenShooter

I've also heard of something called BB Stream that will actually stream the blackberry screen to your PC. Can't find it anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good guide

http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/taking-screenshots-of-blackberry-screen/